# send mouseclick message in .net

Tags: c#

I would like to programmatically send a mouse click from a usercontrol to it's creator when a control is selected in the usercontrol.

I have tried :

```
 private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
 private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern void mouse_event(
    UInt32 dwFlags, // motion and click options 
    UInt32 dx, // horizontal position or change 
    UInt32 dy, // vertical position or change 
    UInt32 dwData, // wheel movement 
    IntPtr dwExtraInfo // application-defined information 
    ); 

    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, new System.IntPtr());
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, new System.IntPtr());
```

But I am not having any success in recieving the event at the parent.

perhaps there is another way for a mouseclick to cascade down?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Control.InvokeOnClick` to trigger the click event for your parent form.
Check out this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180363/c-winforms-usercontrol-mouse-event-help) for details

Answer (score -1):

```
class Parent : Control {
   private Control child; // some child control

   ...

  child_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) { //subscribed to child Click event
    this.OnClick(e); //Fire parent's click event
  }
}
```