# Creating a 'second' mouse to do actions without using your normal one

Tags: c#, client, mouse

I'm looking to develop a program in C# that has a second mouse. What I mean by this is that if I pressed the 1 button on my keyboard, it would click on a certain location on the client window. But when the button is clicked, your normal, visible cursor doesn't move and you can freely control it.

I have no idea if this is possible and I have a feeling it won't be, but if it is... Does anyone have an idea how to do it? Or where I could start?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053162/send-mouseclick-message-in-net, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518397/send-click-message-to-another-application-process, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/el-GR/Vsexpressvb/thread/d4d99ad3-4cb2-423d-9f9d-18df47c7d164. It depends whether you have access to protected methods of the control you want to click.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# - " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: I don't see why there's a problem with moving the cursor.  Just move it back.  Beating the human eye with a modern machine is quite trivial.  Use SendInput().

Comment: It seems like what you're describing is a keyboard shortcut? Or do you need the key press to do multiple actions?

Answer (score 1):

How important is it that the mouse does not move? If not terribly, You could jump the location of the mouse to where you needed to click, simulate the click, and then jump the mouse back to where it was. As this could be done very quickly, it would still give the appearance of having free control over the mouse.